# How to link AWS accounts and navigate between them?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm a freelancer developer. So I have a lot of customers that I also singin into their AWS accounts.

Today I do have a lot of aws users, one for each customer. For me it's a mess to have to logout-login into their accounts every time. I'm using some tricks like incognito mode and switch browser sessions in order to keep active on those accounts.

I already tried AWS SSO or AWS Organizations but it is seems to be more like a big organization with a lot of sub-accounts, not a user that want to easily switch from one account to another.

I would like to easily switch account like google or Microsoft allows me to do.

How can I do it in AWS? Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could use role based cross-account access.
The client would have to provide the role, and set it up in a way that allows you to switch into it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html